# Using the SQL Server Geography data type

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

I am working with a SQL Server database that has a `customer` table in it that contains (among other things) an `address` column. This column houses the full address (street, city, state, zip) as one long text string. We are looking to convert this information into latitude & longitude coordinates for plotting on a map. I've been looking into using the `Geography` data type in SQL Server, but I cannot find any definitive information regarding what data actually needs to be entered into the `Geography` column in the database table.

The question I have: is there a way to use the `Geography` data type to convert the address string (or any part of it, City, Zip, etc.) into latitude & longitude coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're looking to do, you'd need latitude and longitude information. The data type doesn't convert addresses inherently, but there are many services that you can use to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  I know of Google's API, but its limitations on the number of conversions that can be done per minute and per day makes it problematic for us.  Are there others that can be used via vbscript and/or SQL?